# Unable to access app specific internal Storage

Tags: android, storage, screen-orientation, savestate

I'm trying to save state during rotation and repopulate a list with specific files I've created in internal app storage.

```
currentFile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), timeString);
```

After accessing the timeString from an outstate bundle.  It Doesn't let me access the file.

```
currentFile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), timeString);
```

I've used both getCacheDir() and getFilesDir() tested different versions of the code using getAbsolutePath and messing with the prefix using different versions of file://.  I keep getting

```
open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

edit: Eliminated use of local variable to reduce confusion

Comment: Presumably, `uri` is not the same as `timeString + ".mp3"`.

Comment: I've edited the question to reduce confusion.

Comment: No, my point was that (using your edits) the `timeString` that you start with is different than the `timeString` that use later. For example, a filesystem path does not have `file://` in it.

Comment: It's the exact same string used to create the file.  I save it in an independent variable then add it to a bundle during onSaveInstanceState().